# Does mgo have the functionality to sort a specific Slice field for each document from a query result?

Tags: go, mgo

I'm not talking about how to sort `result`. That I know!
It's one of the field in `result` that I want sorted in a specific order.
So let say we have a `result := []A{}` returned by a mgo query:

```
type A struct {
    I  string
    II []B
}
type B struct {
    X  string
    XX int
}
```

In that `result`, I want each `result[i].II` sorted by B.XX

What I'm asking is can I get this kind of sort done by mgo or I'll have to loop on `result` and sort the `A.II` Slice my self ?

Comment: `mgo` definitely doesn't, it's just an interface to MongoDB. It exposes the functionality that MongoDB offers, plus the `bson` library for marshaling/unmarshalling Go types into Mongo's native BSON.

Comment: FYI, in case you were thinking of manually sorting that `[]B`, don't forget you can make a custom slice type (eg `type BSlice []B`) and implement the sort interface: https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with the aggregation engine.

1. $match the documents you want
2. $project the fields you want
3. $unwind the slice
4. $sort the unwound slice using the id and the unwound value as your sort keys
5. $group your sorted slice elements together